# karate- run time error in evaluation of 'karate-config.js'

Tags: karate

I am just trying to run karate script and seems some issue with karate-config.js file.
evaluation of 'karate-config.js' getting failed because there is no variable found called "response".
The code was working fine with same config file earlier.
I am using 0.8.0 version of Karate
Trace-
java.lang.RuntimeException: evaluation of 'karate-config.js' failed

Comment: whats your java version?

Comment: I am using Java 1.8.0 Version

Comment: Release document states that you need to be on a Java version at least 1.8.0_112 or greater. so make sure you have the 112 update

Comment: Thanks for the help. Found out that I was facing this issue because of license headers present in the .js file and karate does not support license headers in .js files.